# How do I run only some makefile commands as root?

Tags: c, makefile, installation, sudo

I have an install target in my Makefile and wish to run some commands that install shared libraries(requires root permissions) and some that install config files into `$HOME/.config`

Usually I'd just tell the user to run sudo make install, however that results in the config file being installed to `/root/.config` instead of the actual users config directory.

How do I work around this issue?
Thanks alot.

Comment: Can you please post the Makefile.

Comment: Don't do both at the same time use two targets one for each purpose also let users install the libraries to non-system locations. You could also use sudo in the makefile rule itself.

Comment: I wont post the makefile, its a bit big.... I dont really want to use 2 targets else the user has to type extra

Comment: The standard and correct solution is to install a default central configuration file along with the software and let the software itself create a custom user-specific file or directory with files`$HOME/.whateverthesoftwareiscalled` as soon as the user makes a configuration change.

Comment: What if someone who didn't install the software tries to run it? They won't have a `$HOME/.config`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change the owner and permissions of the config files, although a `Makefile` that installs per user configuration files, is not a good idea because it would ideally need to find out how many users exist on the system to install the files for each user.

If you use the `install` command, you could even do

```
install -v -m644 -o$(USERNAME) -g$(USERGROUP) $(FILE) $(USERHOME)/.config/$(FILE)
```

A better approach would be to let the program install the default config files from a system wide directory when it doesn't find them, for example

```
/usr/share/my-application/default-config/config.conf
```

and then the program would search for the files in the appropriate directoy and copy them to the `$HOME` directory of the user that is currently running the program, that if the files are modifiable by the user, otherwise you just access them from their system-wide location.